# Warning when not connected via a VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Is there a way in which I can have Ubuntu display a warning when *not* connected to the Internet via a VPN (for example, a pop-up notification)?

I am aware that there are ways to force Ubuntu to *block* all traffic unless connected via a VPN... But what about if all I want is a *warning*?

*Surely* there has to be a way to do this?